# AttributeError: module 'turtle' has no attribute 'forward'

Tags: python, python-3.x, libraries, turtle-graphics

when I use the **IDLE** typing in:

```
import turtle
turtle.forward(100)
```

My program works flawlessly. However when I create a .py file and attempt to execute it, it spits out this error.

```
AttributeError: module 'turtle' has no attribute 'forward'
```

I don't understand why this does not work as it is the same code. I am using python3.7 if that makes a difference. Thanks

Comment: Did you name your script `turtle.py`? You shouldn't have.

Comment: I did originally however when I renamed the file it spat out a different error.

File "drawingmeme.py", line 1, in <module>
    import turtle
ImportError: bad magic number in 'turtle': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'

Comment: Delete the `turtle.pyc` file too. It is a leftover compiled module from your previous trials.